# MPMoviePlayerController shows only black screen - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a View inside a ViewController that I want to add a move player controller to it. But so far I'm only getting a black screen. 
I'm running this on the simulator, and using the apple dev stream which I tested in Safari and it works.

The videoView is added to the controller through an IBOutlet. I'm using Xcode 6 beta 7.

This is all inside a UIViewController.

Declaration of videoView 320x320 (global):

```
    @IBOutlet var videoView: UIView!
```

Declaration of MPMoviePlayerController (global):

```
    var videoPlayer : MPMoviePlayerController = MPMoviePlayerController()
```

Adding videoPlayer to View:

```
            videoURLWithPath = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"
            let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoURLWithPath)
            videoPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming;
            videoPlayer.contentURL = videoURL
            videoPlayer.view.frame = videoView.bounds

            videoView.addSubview(videoPlayer.view)
            videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded

            videoPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            videoPlayer.play()
```

Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

Simulator:

[image]

Update:

I've also tried doing this. Super simple. And I'm still getting the same result. The frame size is set that way so that I can see that the player has actually been added.

```
            let streamURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.thumbafon.com/code_examples/video/segment_example/prog_index.m3u8")
            var streamPlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: streamURL)
            streamPlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 200)
            streamPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
            videoView.addSubview(streamPlayer.view)
            streamPlayer.play()
```

Comment: We would need more information than that, namely how you declare and initialize your player, your player view and implementation of dev stream etc etc. More code would be helpful.

Comment: @Unheilig Declaration and init added. Player view is simply a 320x320 view added to the storyboard, declaration added. Dev stream was taken from apple, it's a basic HLS stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up ditching MPMoviePlayerController and opted to use AVFoundation instead.

Working example:

Global declarations:

```
var player : AVPlayer? = nil
var playerLayer : AVPlayerLayer? = nil
var asset : AVAsset? = nil
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem? = nil
```

inside viewDidLoad:

```
            let videoURLWithPath = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"
            let videoURL = NSURL(string: videoURLWithPath)

            asset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(videoURL) as? AVAsset
            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

            player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem)

            playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
            playerLayer!.frame = videoView.frame
            videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer)

            player!.play()
```

Comment: could i add this to any view and the video in my url would play? how do i set it as the background? thanks

Comment: @BZMWillemsen I'm getting an error for 'Use of unresolved Identifier videoView, where do you declare it? I've tried a multitude of things, I've also had to unwrap 3 variables

Comment: @Gerwin add your own videoView (UIView) separately into your controller. That UIView will cover your player.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `MPMoviePlayerController`, this works perfectly for me:

```
// import MediaPlayer

var moviePlayer : MPMoviePlayerViewController?

@IBAction func playVideo()  {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ra3", ofType:"mp4")
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

    let videoURL = url
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: videoURL )

    if let player = moviePlayer {
        player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.presentViewController(moviePlayer!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        NSLog("no player")
    }
}
```